# when to use tap() and when to use map() in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, angular2-observables

A the document describes the tap() with following code:

```js
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const positions = clicks.pipe(
  tap(ev => console.log(ev)),
  map(ev => ev.clientX),
);
positions.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

but I do not understand why to use tap. Is it just logging. The explanation says

> Map every click to the clientX position of that click, while also
> logging the click event

Comment: `tap()` is an operator made to only perform side-effects. Of course you could put the `console.log()` into `map()` but that's in general discouraged.

Comment: if you put `console.log()` instead of `ev.clientX` - the `x` would be `undefined`, such as logging would return `undefined`. `map` - data transformation, `tap` - side effects(would do nothing to your data).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap)

*Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return an Observable that is identical to the source*

**Example:**

```
tap(value => console.log(value))
```

[Map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map)

*Applies a given project function to each value emitted by the source Observable, and emits the resulting values as an Observable.*

**Example:**

```
map(value => 'prefix' + value)
```

**Why not to use map or other operators for side effects like log**

*You can use map, scan and any other operator that gets a function and returns an individual result to implement side effects. This will make your code very hard to understand/debug/find bugs in the future. Provided that, in general it is not good to use side effects in pipes. Logging can be an exception if you need/want it and don't want to have lot's of subscriptions for every logging point. Therefore tap can be useful. You could adapt this to the following steps:*

1. Try to avoid as many side effects as possible
2. If you need some (logging) use tap to clarify that there is an side effect

**Example for how you could but should not**

```
switchMap(value => {
  console.log(value); // Side effect 1
  const newValue = foo(value);
  console.log(newValue); // Side effect 2
  return of(newValue);
})
```

**Example of how you could do and should**

```
tap(console.log), // Side effect 1
switchMap(value => of(foo(value))),
tap(console.log) // Side effect 2
```

Last word: *When you write initially code that brings not much of an benefit. The larget your project gets and the moment other people try to find bugs it will improve saved time a lot.*

Comment: Where would you put `arr => arr.sort()`? The original array is modified, but would it be good practice to put it in a `tap` rather than `map`?

Comment: Your question is without context and therefore not 100% safe to be correctly answered. But as I can guess you are receiving your `arr` from some observable and you are inbetween a pipe and want to use this value somehow in some subscription later on. As `arr.sort()` already returns you the correct sorted array you can use map like in the answer described.
If you don't want to use the `arr` value in a later subscription, I am asking myself why the `arr.sort()` in general has to be done within the pipe. I would recommend either sticking to rxjs or if you have imperative code - stick to it.

Comment: I mean when the array must be sorted and then used in a later subscription (imagine a list of language choices you want to display in a dropdown - the response does not have them sorted but you want to sort them before displaying). The result would be the same with both `map` and `tap` but is there a best practice? Would unnecessarily returning the same instance of the array with `map` be bad practice? Would introducing changes to the value with `tap` be bad practice? I guess there should be a preference, because otherwise you would have developers mixing both throughout the project.